# how to get the object in a razor page

Tags: .net, razor

I made razorpages using entity based scaffolding (CRUD).

The details, edit and delete page are handed an object to operate on. How do I get my hands on this object? I know the ID of the object is in the url.

I want to use MyClass.someMethod()

Converting
`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MyClass.someField)`
to
`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MyClass.someMethod())`
is no good, as methods are not allowed in this context.

In my PageModel I see:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
```

What I want to do:

```
@{MyClass mc = model.MyClass[id];
    mc.callSomeMethod()}
```

How do I get this id ? Or is there another way to execute someMethod() ?

Answer (score 1):

From the
`ModelPage.OnGetAsync(string id)` I have copied the id to an accessible outside field. It's ugly but it works.

If anyone knows a better solution please tell.

Answer (score 0):

If the id is in the URL you should be to access it in your PageModel like this:

```
HttpContext.Request.Query["id"]
```

In your case:

```
@{MyClass mc = HttpContext.Request.Query["id"];
    mc.callSomeMethod()}
```